# Slick slider Syncing - custom arrow on breakpoints

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slick.js

So i have this multi slider where i use the slick slider sync to make this slider work. Everything works great except when i want to use a different/my own buttons as next previous arrows on mobile screens (768 and below). I have the UI setup correctly as far as showing the correct buttons. But my setup is not recognizing my custom buttons as slick arrow on mobile.

**Regular screen** 
[image]

**Mobile screen** (buttons not working as arrows)
[image]

```
**here is my code**
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  $(".home-nav-slider-bg").slick({
     slidesToShow: 1,
     slidesToScroll: 1,
     arrows: false,
     fade: true,
     asNavFor: '.home-nav-slider-slider',
  });


  $(".home-nav-slider-slider").slick({
     slidesToShow: 1,
     slidesToScroll: 1,
     centerPadding: '30px',
     asNavFor: '.home-nav-slider-bg',
     centerMode: false,
     focusOnSelect: true,
     speed: 500,
     arrows: true,
     //fade: true,
     responsive: [
        {
           breakpoint: 768,
           settings: {
              nextArrow: $('.home-nav-slider-media-control button.right slick-next').get().map(function (v) { return v.outerHTML }).join(),
              prevArrow: $('.home-nav-slider-media-control button.left slick-prev').get().map(function (v) { return v.outerHTML }).join()
           }
        }


     ]
  });

  $(window).resize(function () {
     $('.home-nav-slider-slider')[0].slick.refresh();
  });
});

jQuery(window).on('load', function () {
  function getImage() {
     jQuery(".home-nav-slider-image-holder").each(function () {
        var imgSrc = $(this).find("img").attr("src");
        $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + imgSrc + ')');
     });
  }
  getImage();
});




var $status = $('.home-nav-slider-slideCount');
var $slickElement = $('.home-nav-slider-slickElement');

$slickElement.on('init reInit afterChange', function (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
  var i = (currentSlide ? currentSlide : 0) + 1;
  $status.text(i + '/' + slick.slideCount);
});

$('.home-nav-slider-slider').on('afterChange', function (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {

  console.log(event);
  console.log(slick);
  console.log(currentSlide);
  console.log(nextSlide);

});
```

```css
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  font-family: 'Teko', sans-serif;
}
html {
  font-size: 18px;
}
@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 540px;
 }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 720px;
 }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 960px;
 }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 1400px;
 }
}
h1, .h1 {
  font-size: 3.815rem;
}
h2, .h2 {
  font-size: 2.441rem;
}
h3, .h3 {
  font-size: 1.563rem;
}
h4, .h4 {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  font-family: 'Teko', sans-serif;
}
.home-nav-slider-main .home-nav-slider-title h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: normal;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .57);
  line-height: 110%;
}
.home-nav-slider-main .home-nav-slider-media-control button {
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.home-nav-slider-main .home-nav-slider-slider {
  color: #fff;
}
.home-nav-slider-main .home-nav-slider-slider .slick-prev, .home-nav-slider-main .home-nav-slider-slider .slick-next {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  height: 2.1rem;
  width: 40px;
  z-index: 1;
  top: -1rem !important;
}
.home-nav-slider-main .home-nav-slider-slider .slick-list {
  padding-top: 1rem;
}
.home-nav-slider-main .home-nav-slider-slider .slick-list:before {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
.home-nav-slider-main .slick-prev:before, .home-nav-slider-main .slick-next:before {
  font-family: 'Ionicons';
}
.home-nav-slider-main .slick-next:before {
  content: '\f3d6';
}
.home-nav-slider-main .slick-prev:before {
  content: '\f3d5';
}
.home-nav-slider-main .home-nav-slider-image-holder {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
.home-nav-slider-main .home-nav-slider-image-holder img {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.home-nav-slider-main .home-nav-slider-bg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.home-nav-slider-main .home-nav-slider-bg div {
  height: 100%;
}
.home-nav-slider-main .home-nav-slider-bg .slick-slide {
  margin: 0px;
}
.home-nav-slider-main .home-nav-slider-bg img {
  height: 100vh;
  width: auto;
}
.home-nav-slider-main .home-nav-slider-wrap {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
}
.home-nav-slider-main .home-nav-slider-slideCount {
  position: relative;
  left: 6rem;
  top: -10px;
  color: #fff;
}
.home-nav-slider-main .slick-slide {
  margin: 0px 3px;
}
.home-nav-slider-main .home-slider-gradient-wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.home-nav-slider-main .home-slider-gradient-wrap:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
 /* background-color: #000;
  */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#33000000', endColorstr='#b3000000', GradientType=0);
}
.home-nav-slider-main .home-slider-gradient-wrap .container .row {
  height: 100vh;
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .home-nav-slider-main .slick-next {
    left: 2.18rem;
 }
  .home-nav-slider-main .slick-prev {
    left: 0px;
 }
}
@media (max-width: 992px) {
  .home-nav-slider-main .home-nav-slider-slider {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
 }
  .home-nav-slider-main .slick-prev {
    left: 0px;
 }
  .home-nav-slider-main .slick-next {
    left: 40px;
 }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .home-nav-slider-main .home-nav-slider-slider-text {
    display: block !important;
    text-align: left;
 }
  .home-nav-slider-main .home-nav-slider-slider-text p {
    text-align: left !important;
 }
  .home-nav-slider-main .home-nav-slider-slider-text p br {
    display: none;
 }
  .home-nav-slider-main .slider-home h1 {
    text-align: left;
 }
}
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
  .home-nav-slider-main .home-slider-gradient-wrap .container .row {
    height: auto;
 }
  .home-nav-slider-main .home-nav-slider-wrap {
    height: auto;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
   <title>slick 2-in-1-new</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href=" https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.css" />
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Teko:400,500,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
   <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
   <div class="home-nav-slider-main">
      <section class="home-nav-slider-wrap  mb-0 pt-11">
         <div class="home-slider-gradient-wrap">
            <div class="home-nav-slider-bg">

               <div class="home-nav-slider-image-holder">
                  <img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/9fvw247x7ml90mf/canadaN.jpg?dl=1" alt="">
               </div>
               <div class="home-nav-slider-image-holder">
                  <img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/5x8p2z5cvip5u38/chicago.jpg?dl=1" alt="">
               </div>



            </div>
            <div class="container">
               <div class="row">
                  <div class=" col-lg-12 align-self-center">
                     <div class="home-nav-slider-title">
                        <h1> Hello<br>Slider</h1>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-12 align-self-center d-none d-lg-block ">
                     <span class="home-nav-slider-slideCount"></span>

                     <div class="home-nav-slider-slider home-nav-slider-slickElement ">

                        <div>
                           <div
                              class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between home-nav-slider-slider-text mb-3">
                              <div class="pr-5">
                                 <h6>
                                    hello
                                 </h6>
                              </div>
                              <div class="pr-5">
                                 <p>
                                    Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate, officiis
                                    blanditiis suscipit rerum mollitia natus ipsam. Rerum id eligendi reiciendis dolorum
                                    excepturi, quidem incidunt. Accusantium tenetur incidunt ratione laudantium aut.

                                 </p>
                              </div>
                              <div>
                                 <a href="#">
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary">
                                       click this
                                    </button>
                                 </a>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>

                        <div>
                           <div
                              class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between home-nav-slider-slider-text mb-3">
                              <div class="pr-5">
                                 <h6>
                                    hello
                                 </h6>
                              </div>
                              <div class="pr-5">
                                 <p>
                                    Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate, officiis
                                    blanditiis suscipit rerum mollitia natus ipsam. Rerum id eligendi reiciendis dolorum
                                    excepturi, quidem incidunt. Accusantium tenetur incidunt ratione laudantium aut.

                                 </p>
                              </div>
                              <div>
                                 <a href="#">
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary">
                                       click this
                                    </button>
                                 </a>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>


                     </div>
                  </div>

               </div>

            </div>
            <!-- small screen slide control -->
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-end d-lg-none home-nav-slider-media-control">
               <button class="btn btn-primary left "><i class="ion-ios-arrow-thin-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
               <button class="btn btn-primary right "><i class="ion-ios-arrow-thin-right"
                     aria-hidden="true"></i></button>

            </div>



         </div>
      </section>
   </div>


   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/extra-jquery.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This code part is incorrect:**

```
settings: {
    nextArrow: $('.home-nav-slider-media-control button.right slick-next').get().map(function (v) { return v.outerHTML }).join(),
    prevArrow: $('.home-nav-slider-media-control button.left slick-prev').get().map(function (v) { return v.outerHTML }).join()
}
```

1. You don't have these combinations in HTML:
    
   `.home-nav-slider-media-control button.right slick-next`
   `.home-nav-slider-media-control button.left slick-prev`
2. You shouldn't copy HTML code of the buttons, you should point to them.

**Correct code:**

```
settings: {
    nextArrow: $('.home-nav-slider-media-control button.right'),
    prevArrow: $('.home-nav-slider-media-control button.left')
}
```

**Here is the working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nsmcan/y5g8w4d2/)**

---

### **More to add:**

This slick slider module seems to be quite buggy and kills the custom control buttons when resized to the smaller screen size. Also it doesn't generate the breakpoint events.

I have added some additional code and updated jsfiddle to ensure your test page keeps working after multiple window resizes.

It could be optimized, but at least it works totally correctly now.

Comment: thanks very much. I modified little bit above, correct code part was the main issue. You are right about slider being buggy on screen sizes

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Sergey Nudnov

changing the next,prev arrow jquery to the correct code by sergey seems to gave my custom buttons control right away. That was the main issue .

But like surgey suggested slider seems to be buggy when resizing screens. I modified sergeys code little bit due my custom buttons were disappearing on certain screen size, this modification seems to fix the **Maximum call stack size exceeded error** i was getting when going back and forth on the screen size, screen size checking caused this error but not sure why this small change fixed it, let me know if anyone can point out why that fixed it . alos changed all breakpoints to 992 , seems to work better. Any way thanks surgey.

**surgey code for small screen before slide change**

```js
$('.home-nav-slider-slider').on('beforeChange', function (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
 var width = $(window).width();
  if(width <= 768 && !$('.home-nav-slider-media-control button.right').length)
  {
  $("#small-control").html(`
<div class="d-flex justify-content-end d-lg-none home-nav-slider-media-control">
                 <button class="btn btn-primary left "><i class="ion-ios-arrow-thin-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                 <button class="btn btn-primary right "><i class="ion-ios-arrow-thin-right"
                       aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
  `);
    $('.home-nav-slider-slider').slick('slickSetOption',
     "responsive", [
        {
           breakpoint: 768,
           settings: {
              nextArrow: $('.home-nav-slider-media-control button.right'),
              prevArrow: $('.home-nav-slider-media-control button.left')
           }
        }
      ], true
   );
  }

});
```

**modified to this**

```js
$('.home-nav-slider-slider').on('beforeChange', function (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
   var width = $(window).width();
   if (width <= 992 && !$('.home-nav-slider-media-control button.right').length) {
      $(".home-nav-slider-media-control").html('<button class="btn btn-primary left slick-arrow" style=""><i class="ion-ios-arrow-thin-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></button><button class="btn btn-primary right slick-arrow" style=""><i class="ion-ios-arrow-thin-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>');
      $('.home-nav-slider-slider').slick('slickSetOption',
         "responsive", [
            {
               breakpoint: 992,
               settings: {
                  nextArrow: $('.home-nav-slider-media-control button.right'),
                  prevArrow: $('.home-nav-slider-media-control button.left')
               }
            }
         ], true
      );
   }

});
```